# Is there any solution to get rid of duplicate key error in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, post

I am creating the pinterest clone and I am having some problem when I uploading posts. The problem is about the duplicate key error when try to save the second post and so on.

This is my user schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DataVault');


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: String,

  post: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Post",
    }
  ],
  ProfileImage: String,
});

userSchema.plugin(plm);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This is my Post schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/DataVault');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  PostText: {
    type: String,
  },
  image: {
    type: String
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  }
});

postSchema.plugin(plm);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

This is the route where I create post and save

```
// post creaetion and uploading
router.post("/postUpload", isLoggedIn, uploads.single("postImage"), async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(404).send("Something Went Wrong!!!");
  }

  const user = await userModel.findOne({ username: req.session.passport.user });
  const post = await postModel.create({
    PostText: req.body.fileCaption,
    image: req.file.filename,
    user: user._id
  });

  user.post.push(post._id);
  await user.save();

  console.log("Post Successfully Saved ✌");
  res.redirect("/profile");
});
```

This is the error I am facing when I upload the second post with the same account (USER):

> throw new error_1.MongoServerError(res.writeErrors[0]);
> ^
>
> MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: DataVault.posts index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }
>
> at InsertOneOperation.execute (D:\backend\Codes\pinterest\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:48:19)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async executeOperationAsync (D:\backend\Codes\pinterest\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:106:16) {
> index: 0,
> code: 11000,
> keyPattern: { username: 1 },
> keyValue: { username: null },
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
> }

Comment: You can use [upsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#upsert) but I have no idea how to do this in mongoose.

Comment: Check your database. It looks like when you create your initial user the `username` is missing and mongoose adds a default value of `null` instead. Given that you have declared `username` with a `unique` index mongodb won't let you save another user if that username is missing (you can't have 2x null). Can you share the code where you create your user as it's likely the `username` property isn't being extracted from `req.body`, assuming you used a form submission/postman to create your user.

Answer (score 0):

The error come from your `userModel.findOne` with return none. so `user.save()` will create a new user with username is null. After that, a client call api but the result `findOne by usename` is none again that make sever create a new user and duplicate with username = null.

To solve this error, You can check the result of user after `userModel.findOne`. Ex: `if (!user) return res.status(400).send("User not found!");`

```
router.post("/postUpload", isLoggedIn, uploads.single("postImage"), async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(404).send("Something Went Wrong!!!");
  }

  const user = await userModel.findOne({ username: req.session.passport.user });
  // Check user exist before create post
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("User not found!");
  const post = await postModel.create({
    PostText: req.body.fileCaption,
    image: req.file.filename,
    user: user._id
  });

  user.post.push(post._id);
  await user.save();

  console.log("Post Successfully Saved ✌");
  res.redirect("/profile");
});
```